# running python script as startup service ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

My python script takes multiple directories as input from user and I want that the user should input the directories for once only and then the program should run continuously over the same directories even after the system boots without asking the user again. I want to use Supervisor configuration to set this up. Any help ??

Comment: Do you need it really after system boot even when the user isn't logged in or is it enough to run the script automatically after user login in as a background task?

Comment: I want to use supervisor configuration to make the script run as it was before the boot. help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a cron-job or create a service init script (see the manual for how to write a init-script under the current Ubuntu version).

Doing a cronjob:

```
EDITOR=nano; crontab -e
@reboot cd /home/user/place_where_script_is; python3 myscript.py param1 param2
```

There's no efficient way for the user to input data to startup script, mainly because they run in a root environment.
A cron-job always runs in the environment where you invoked `crontab -e` (hopefully the users environment) but even then..
You can not interact with it because it's run in a separate "shell".

### Unix socket?

In your script, add a listening socket on a unix socket.
in your `.bashrc` script (not sure where Ubuntu has it's post X startup scripts), invoke `callMyScript.py` that connects to the unix socket and sends instructions there.

This way you can interact with the cronjob/service script.

## Here's how you keep track if a service is dead or not

**PID** files is the key:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
pidfile = '/var/run/MyApplication.pid'

def pid_exists(pid):
    """Check whether pid exists in the current process table."""
    if pid < 0:
        return False
    try:
        os.kill(pid, 0)
    except OSError, e:
        return e.errno == errno.EPERM
    else:
        return True

if isfile(pidfile):
    with open(pidfile) as fh:
        thepid = fh.read()

    pidnr = int(thepid)
    if pid_exists(pidnr):
        exit(1) # The previous instance is still running
    else:
        remove(pidfile) # Prev instance is dead, remove pidfile

# Create a pid-file with the active PID written in it
with open(pidfile, 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(str(getpid()))

## Your code goes here...

remove(pidfile)
```

This way you can convert your Cron job to look like:

```
EDITOR=nano; crontab -e
* * * */1 cd /home/user/place_where_script_is; python3 myscript.py param1 param2
```

Which will run the script each minute, and if the script is dead or not started the script will start up again.

Same goes for `service status-all myapp` if you've written a init script, the init script will check the PID file (you'd have to write this in your init script and check the PID yourself much like the above Python code) and see if the process is dead.

Comment: I want to keep running the script using supervisor . suggestions ??

Comment: @kraken2242 made a suggestion on how to solve it in Python, use a similar approach in bash (to check a PID) and write your own init script. I use `systemd` which is a completely different approach to init scripts so I can't test my code there for i can not write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your crontab

```
crontab -e
```

Add the following line, which will get executed when your computer boot up:

```
@reboot python /path/to/your/script.py
```

Make sure have at least one empty line at the end. 
As to restarting from where your script left off, you have to program that into your application logic.